# ILIKE first word match in string postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have following query

```
SELECT
    N."@Nomenclature",
    N."Title",
    N."Folder",
    N."Folder@",
    True is_found,
    3 AS rank
FROM
    "Nomenclature" N
WHERE
    'washing hair' :: TEXT IS NOT NULL
    AND "Title" ILIKE '%' || 'washing hair' :: text || '%'
```

This query does not return anything. If i query only `'washing'` this query returns `'washing head'` which is correct. What should i do then i query `'washing hair'` the result will be `'washing head'` as the word `'washing'` is a partial match?

Comment: You may find https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-DOCUMENT interesting.

Comment: What role is "hair" supposed to perform in your query?  If none, then why is there?  If it has a role, your example surely doesn't illustrate it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is much more complex than LIKE matching. Maybe this can get you started: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/pgtrgm.html